# I am getting 2 different row counts from the same statement executed in different locations

Tags: oracle, plsql, lag

I have a statement that collapses date ranges and I am getting the proper collapsed version when executing the SQL by iteself and when inserting it into a nested table in a procedure I am getting a row that should have been collapsed into the other row.

```
           SELECT  client_pk,
                   plan_id,
                   grp,
                   MIN(start_dt) start_dt, 
                   MAX(end_dt) end_dt
              FROM (
                SELECT client_pk
                       plan_id,
                       start_dt,
                       end_dt,
                       MAX(grp) OVER (PARTITION BY plan_id ORDER BY start_dt ASC) grp 
                    FROM (
                    SELECT mp.client_pk,
                           mp.plan_id,
                           CASE 
                                WHEN (LAG(mp.end_dt) OVER (PARTITION BY mp.plan_id ORDER BY mp.start_dt ASC)) BETWEEN mp.start_dt-1 AND 
                                                                                                                        NVL(mp.end_dt,to_date('12/31/9999','MM/DD/YYYY'))
                                    THEN NULL
                            ELSE ROWNUM
                           END grp,  
                           mp.start_dt,
                           NVL(mp.end_dt,to_date('12/31/9999','MM/DD/YYYY')) end_dt
                      FROM client_plan mp
                          )
                      )
                 GROUP BY grp, plan_id, client_pk
```

So I have an initial result set from the inner most query to give a ROWNUM of:

```
client_pk   PLAN_ID GRP start_dt    end_dt
8752        25171   3   1/1/2016    3/31/2016
8752        25171   1   2/1/2016    1/31/2016
```

and by the end, it is collapsed appropriately when execute as a stand alone query

```
client_pk   PLAN_ID GRP start_dt    end_dt
8752        25171   3   1/1/2016    3/31/2016
```

But when run though a procedure that dumps these records into a nested table that will then eventually be inserted into the DB, both rows are still returned.

```
    SELECT plan_spans_obj(client_pk, plan_id, start_dt, end_dt)
      BULK COLLECT INTO plan_spans_ins_tbl
      FROM ( 
       SELECT  client_pk,
               plan_id,
               start_dt, 
               end_dt
         FROM ( SELECT client_pk,
                       plan_id,
                       grp,
                       MIN(start_dt) start_dt, 
                       MAX(end_dt) end_dt
                  FROM (
                    SELECT client_pk
                           plan_id,
                           start_dt,
                           end_dt,
                           MAX(grp) OVER (PARTITION BY plan_id ORDER BY start_dt ASC) grp 
                        FROM (
                        SELECT mp.client_pk,
                               mp.plan_id,
                               CASE 
                                    WHEN (LAG(mp.end_dt) OVER (PARTITION BY mp.plan_id ORDER BY mp.start_dt ASC)) BETWEEN mp.start_dt-1 AND 
                                                                                                                            NVL(mp.end_dt,to_date('12/31/9999','MM/DD/YYYY'))
                                        THEN NULL
                                ELSE ROWNUM
                               END grp,  
                               mp.start_dt,
                               NVL(mp.end_dt,to_date('12/31/9999','MM/DD/YYYY')) end_dt
                          FROM client_plan mp
                              )
                          )
                     GROUP BY grp, plan_id, client_pk
                 )
              );
```

So how am I getting 2 different results from the same query, just executed differently, is it an order of operation different depending on where it is executed.

Also, the extra record is essentially a negative time span, end date being before the start date but this is handled  in the query.

Comment: Can you add the raw data for that client_pk and plan_id? I'm pretty sure it's because you're abusing `ROWNUM`, but I'd like to be able to reproduce it before rewriting it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that I didn't initialize the collection.  Can't believe it was something like that but apparently so.  Seems to be working now.

Comment: You don't need to initialise a collection before you bulk-collect into it. Maybe you had uncommitted changes or something? Still as long as it works ..

Comment: Uncommitted changes was my first thought too... Who knows.